# How to measure the variance from reading to reading

Tags: variance, standard-deviation

I have some values being read by physical sensors. Two of the values from nice lines which are very clear, but the third is all over the place. The problem is calculating a metric to show that the data is almost unusable. I can't use the variance of the data set as the variance is roughly the same as the other readings, it just jumps around a lot more. For a better idea of what I'm trying to say look here:

[image]

Comment: Considering your problem from a purely statistical perspective, my recommendations would be to use autoregressive (p) model to see if we could say the future value of $y$ depends on the previous value. The space between each peak and trough seem like there is some pattern in that.

Alternatively, consider estimation of first differences to see if there are any relationships between them.